# What happens to the unspecified arguments in function()?

Tags: c, function

I have been reading the [difference between `function()` and `function(void)` in C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/287002), and I came to know that

> an empty parameter list in a function *declaration* indicates that the
>   function takes an *unspecified* number of parameters

So [I ran this code](https://godbolt.org/z/dy_sVh):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun();

int main(void)
{
    fun(12, 13.22, 1234567890987654321, "wow", 'c');
}

void fun()
{
    printf("What happened to those arguments?");
}
```

---

I don't understand why C allows this. All the posts I've read so far related to this say things like it's bad practice to use it, it is obsolescent, etc. Also from the above code, I think the type of those arguments is also unspecified. So I just want to know the reason behind "unspecified arguments of unspecified type":

- What can be done with those arguments?
- Is it possible to access those arguments within the function?

Comment: C11 draft standard n1570: *6.5.2.2 Function calls 6 If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that does not include a
prototype, [...] If the number of arguments does not equal the number of parameters, the
behavior is undefined.*

Comment: At the point of declaration the number (and types) of the arguments is unspecified. However the usage of the function **must** correspond to the number (and types) of its definition. `int foo(); /*declaration*/ int main(void) { foo(42) /*UB*/; foo(3.14159); return 0; } /*definition*/ int foo(double x) { return x; }` ==> indented ==> https://ideone.com/4zzlTV

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for supporting the notation is historical.  Before the first C standard (C89/C90), you couldn't use prototypes in C; prototypes were one of the biggest and most important features of Standard C.  All function declarations, therefore, were written the 'empty parentheses' style (when they were written at all; most functions that returned `int` were not declared at all).  The type `void` was also added in C89/C90, though some compilers supported it before the standard was finalized.

Because it was crucial to the success of C89/C90 that existing code should mostly continue to work, the empty parentheses style had to be allowed by the standard.  So, your code might have been written in pre-standard C as:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fun();  /* This declaration would probably have been absent */

int main(void)
{
    fun(12, 13.22, 1234567, "wow", 'c');
    return 0;   /* This was required until C99 to give reliable exit status */
}

fun(i, d, l, s, c)      /* No return type - implicitly returns int */
long l;                 /* Defined out of sequence - bad style, but legal */
char c;                 /* Passed as int; converted to char in function */
char *s;                /* Should define all pointer arguments */
double d;               /* No definition of i; it was an int by default */
{
    printf("This is what happened to those arguments:\n");
    printf("i = %d\n", i);
    printf("d = %f\n", d);
    printf("l = %ld\n", l);
    printf("s = [%s]\n", s);
    printf("c = %c\n", c);
    /* No return statement - don't use the value from the function */
}
```

<sup>For the curious: you could omit the `char *s;` line in the function definition, and it still compiled and produced the same output.  It was a bad idea to try that, though.  You could replace the line `int fun();` with `static fun();` and the code compiles cleanly when no diagnostics are requested.</sup>

You get no warnings even now if you compile this file (`old31.c`) with GCC 9.3.0 using:

```
$ gcc -std=c90 -o old31 old31.c
$
```

Your example as written is skirting around the backwards compatibility provisions.  Using `void` means it was new code (it would not have been valid in many pre-standard C compilers because it used `void`).  And new code should not exploit the backwards-compatibility provisions without a good reason.  That was true in 1991 as well as in the current millennium (but in 1991, there were a lot more good reasons to exploit the backwards-compatibility provisions).  Good pre-standard code usually listed all parameters in the order they were used.  Omitted definitions and out of sequence definitions were not entirely satisfactory.

You asked:

> - What can be done with those arguments?

In the code in the question, nothing can be done with the arguments.  The caller pushes the values onto the stack, and pops them off when the function returns.  The called function is unaware of their existence and can do nothing with them.

> - Is it possible to access those arguments within the function?

No — not using any standard mechanism.

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between a function *declaration* and a function *definition* when there is an empty parameter list.

Section 6.7.6.3p14 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) states:

> An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of
>   the function.  An empty list  in  a  function  declarator  that  is 
>   part  of  a  definition  of  that  function  specifies  that  the
>   function  has  no  parameters.  The  empty  list  in  a  function 
>   declarator  that  is  not  part  of  a definition of that function
>   specifies that no information about the number or types of the
>   parameters is supplied.

What this means is that this declaration:

```
void fun();
```

Means `fun` takes an unknown number of parameters.  While this definition:

```
void fun()
{
    printf("What happened to those arguments?");
}
```

Means that `fun` takes no parameters.  So this function call:

```
fun(12, 13.22, 1234567890987654321, "wow", 'c');
```

Is invalid and invoked [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the number of parameters in the call don't match the actual number of parameters.  This is spelled out in section 6.5.2.2p6 regarding the function call operator `()`:

> If  the  expression  that  denotes  the  called  function  has  a 
>   type  that  does  not  include  a prototype,  the  integer  promotions 
>   are  performed  on  each  argument,  and  arguments  that have 
>   type `float` are  promoted  to `double`.  These  are  called  the *default 
>   argument promotions*.  If  the  number  of  arguments  does  not  equal 
>   the  number  of  parameters,  the behavior is undefined.  If the
>   function is defined with a type that includes a prototype, and either 
>   the  prototype  ends  with  an  ellipsis  (`, ...`)  or  the  types  of 
>   the  arguments  after promotion are not compatible with the types of
>   the parameters, the behavior is undefined.If  the  function  is 
>   defined  with  a  type  that  does  not  include  a  prototype,  and 
>   the  types  of the  arguments  after  promotion  are  not  compatible 
>   with  those  of  the  parameters  after promotion, the behavior is
>   undefined, except for the following cases:
>
> - one   promoted   type   is   a   signed   integer   type,   the   other   promoted   type   is   the corresponding unsigned integer type,
>     and the value is representable in both types;
> - both  types  are  pointers  to  qualified  or  unqualified  versions  of  a  character  type  or `void`.

As for *why* this is allowed, it is legacy behavior that goes back to pre-standardized versions of C where the type of variables and the return type of functions defaulted to `int` and the method of declaring functions differed from what they are now.